# Closure of the exterior of a unit disc

Tags: real-analysis

What is the closure of the set $\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2> 1\right\}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Any guesses?  Do you have to prove your answer?

Comment: Can you say what's the definition of closure?

Answer (score 1):

The logical answer is $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} | x^2 + y^2 \geq 1\},$ isn't it?
Let's try to prove that. We know that if $A$ is a set, $\overline{A},$ the closure of that set, is equal to $A \space  \cup \space A' ,$ where $A'$ denotes the set of limit points of $A$. Can you find $A'$?